# Remove a row in pandas dataframe if multiple columns contains specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried looking for an answer to this question but haven't found anything that works for me. I want to remove rows in which certain columns contain specific values. In my case, I want to remove rows where **each** column that starts with "user" in that row contains the value "pass". E.g. if I have the following dataframe:

```
idx   start   end  user1   user2 
0     1       3    pass     pass   
1     4       5   burger   burger 
2     6       7   nuggets    cola 
3     10     15     pass    burger
```

I'd like to remove row 0, but not row 3 as only one of the columns contains the value "pass". Would appreciate any help!

***Update:*** The names and amount of user columns could increase, e.g. there could be user1, user2, user3 and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
df = df[~df.filter(like='user').apply(set, axis=1).eq({'pass'})]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,2,5], [6,2,9], ['pass', 'pass', 1], [1, 2, 'pass']])

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
display(df)
```

[image]

```
df[(df['one'] != 'pass') & (df['two'] != 'pass')]
```

[image]

as you can see you can pass multiple conditions for your indexation in Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.drop((df.loc[(df['user1'] == 'pass') && df['user2'] == 'pass']).index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the DataFrame with conditionals.

```
df[(df['user1'] != 'pass') & (df['user2'] != 'pass')]
```

If you want to make this the new df just use:

```
df = df[(df['user1'] != 'pass') & (df['user2'] != 'pass')]
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: the names and amount of user columns could increase :) e.g. there could be user1, user2, user3 and so on